# How to change the default images path and direct it to the external directory

Tags: media, files, uri

I just want to know if there is anyway set drupal to upload images to the directory outside the drupal installation like loc*lhost/site-name/image-upload/... rather than 
loc*lhost/site-name/drupal/sites/all/default/.... My drupal installation directory is loc*lhost/site-name/drupal/

Thank you
JOnas

Answer (score 1):

Use **Private File System**, go to `admin/config/media/file-system` and provide the private file system path. After saving it, select  **Private local files served by Drupal** as `Default download method`. After that edit your image field and choose `Private Files` as **Upload Destination**

Note : It should be writable by Drupal and not accessible over the web.

Comment: Than you very much wolverine, it works now

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute URLs. So assuming that you drupal directory is at /loc*lhost/site-name/drupal and you want the files to be stored in /loc*lhost/site-name/image-upload, you can enter /loc*lhost/site-name/image-upload in the public or private image directory. Make sure that this directory is writeable by the web server.

Comment: Than you very much Neerav, it works now